# ошибка javax.servlet.ServletException: Class home.web.Type is not a Servlet

Tags: java, servlet

есть код класса:

```
package home.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public  class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
@Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
        pw.print("<h1>Hello, world!</h1>");
    }
}
```

есть web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>home.web.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

есть maven pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>site</groupId>
    <artifactId>form</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

почему тогда на выходе: http://localhost:8080/form/hello:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Class home.web.HelloWorldServlet is not a Servlet
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

и:

```
   java.lang.ClassCastException: home.web.HelloWorldServlet cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

заранее спасибо.

Comment: А у вас есть класс `home.web.Type`?

Comment: приношу извинения, исправил вывод. просто еще другой класс тестил.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `<scope>provided</scope>` в тег `dependency `

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!!!!!!! И низкий поклон, добрый человек.

Comment: Пожалуйста) Я написал это в ответ - вы можете отметить его "верным", нажав на галочку слева от тела поста)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что либа с сервлетами не должна входить в итоговый `war` файл, а должна использоваться только для компиляции. Такого поведения можно добиться добавив `<scope>provided</scope>` в тег `dependency`, содержащий либу с сервлетами.